# Is it possible to insert additional data for each packet inside the RTMP protocol?

Tags: node.js, encryption, tcp, video-streaming, rtmp

I'm currently working on a simple implementation of the streaming platform used in the movie and the books the circle.

In the story secrets are lies and every data should be accessible to everyone. Users can stream their data to a server which allows users to watch. Now the stream should have integrity checks but should not encrypt its data with the purpose of hiding information. To solve this I wanted to:

- Setup a client (android) that streams their camera over RTMP and sends a digital signature as way of providing authentication, non repudiation and a way to check the integrity.
- Setup a server that takes in the data, confirms the identity of the stream by reading out the signature and validating the hash. The server then relays this stream to the webclient..
- Have a web client where viewers can watch the stream, while also having the same type of security as used by publishing the stream.

Now there are a few ways I thought about implementing this, but the most beautiful way without impacting latency a lot would be to modify the RTMP packets to be able to send additional data along every step. I read in the official docs for RTMP that the header leaves room for only 2 bytes which isn't enough to support a sha256 signature. Now I'm not a streaming protocol expert so any additional help besides pointing me at the docs would be greatly appreciated.

I have had succes by calling the OnMetaData but this is only send once per stream, so it leaves the stream vulnerable after the initial handshake. I have mainly worked with the [Node-Media-Server](https://github.com/illuspas/Node-Media-Server) package.

TLDR: Need a way to add a digital signature to my RTMP protocol, for science.
Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Is it possible to insert the hash in the packet? Or is this the wrong approach all together?

Comment: You can put anything you want into script tags.

Comment: @szatmary Sorry could you elaborate, I was unable to find anything regarding script tags in the specifation https://www.adobe.com/devnet/rtmp.html

Comment: RTMP carries FLV. Look at the FLV specification.

Comment: @szatmary this would solve the issue during media transport, but would not secure the initial handshake and other types of RTMP transport besides the data transfer. I will look into the flv stream itself, so thank you for that input.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understood your question, you propably do not need to add signature into each RTMP packet. 
RTMP connection sets once for a client and begins with a handshake. 
C1 packet is 1536 bytes long and has a *Random data (1528 bytes)* which is:

> This field can contain any arbitrary      values.  Since each endpoint
>   has to distinguish between the      response to the handshake it has
>   initiated and the handshake      initiated by its peer,this data
>   SHOULD send something sufficiently      random.  But there is no need
>   for cryptographically-secure      randomness, or even dynamic values.

You can use it to pass your hashes and authenticate client on server side, if everything is ok — proceed connection or just close it if something goes wrong.

Comment: Alright this is something we have looked at, the problem is that the handshake only occurs once. We want to make sure that no video data has been tampered with during the entire stream. Putting it in the header would be the nicest way, however besides the handshake the headers leaves no room for 256 bit signatures. I hope I understood you correctly. Let me know if my answer makes sense.